# Is there any provision available to import excel into existing Azure sql table without overwriting?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm new to .NET and currently working on a project using Azure SQL Database and MVC4.

I've created tables manually on Azure SQL Database using SSMS and have entered some values into those tables.

Now I've attempted to import data from an Excel sheet into those tables. When I tried using "Task --> Import" wizard, it's creating a new table on Azure SQL Database instead of updating the existing table.

What I need is: when I import from Excel, the data from the Excel sheet should append with the existing table's data and should not create a new table on the Azure SQL Database.

It would be very helpful if someone could please provide a solution for this scenario. If you have any clarifying questions, please let me know.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2an81.png

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or two of the menu and wizard you are using?

Comment: @cbattlegear: Thanks for your response. I've mentioned the URL for the image above. For any clarifications, please let me know.

Comment: @Arun, in SSMS, when you right-click on a database in the Object Explorer, under tasks, is import data an options for you? If so, what version of SSMS are you using?